# Time complexity for a triple for loop

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

**What have I done before**

[Asymptotic analysis of three nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052528/asymptotic-analysis-of-three-nested-for-loops)

I was solving the time complexity of this algorithm.
seeing that the outer loop runs `n` times and inner loop 1 runs `i` times, I applied the summation and got the two outer loops' complexity to be n(n plus 1)/2. 
Then the inner loop executes j times equals to summation of j from j is 0 to j is n(n plus 1)/2. This yields the total complexity of O(n4).

**The problem**

[Asymptotic analysis of three nested for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052528/asymptotic-analysis-of-three-nested-for-loops)

Seems like my answer is wrong. Where did I made the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You counted the wrong thing.  The inner loop executes `j` times, and `j` is always less than `n`.  Therefore, for each of your n(n-1)/2 times the inner loop *starts*, the body of the inner loop will be executed less than n times, which means the total number of times the loop executes is at most n(n-1)/2 * O(n), which is at most O(n^3).  What I think you did was double-counting.  You tried to use the "summation" of `j`, which is the total number of times the `for (int j...` loop executes.  But that information is *already* contained in the computation you already made, n(n-1)/2; using that information again and multiplying it with n(n-1)/2 is double-counting.

Comment: Thanks! Now I solved it like this: the outer loop runs n times. Middle loop runs n(n + 1)/2 times. And the inner loop runs from 0 to n(n + 1)/2 in a series of summation - and calculating the sum, it comes.out to be n/2 *(n(n + 1)/2) which is equal to O(n3)!